# Could const_cast ever return a null pointer for inputs other than null pointer?

Tags: c++, casting, const-cast

[cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/const_cast) explains that one possible `const_cast` conversion is a *"null pointer value may be converted to the null pointer value of new_type"*.

Is there any other way `const_cast` can return a null pointer?

Comment: [expr.const.cast](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.const.cast) lists all the cases, it is easy to see that the answer is no.

Comment: note that here C++ (surprisingly) misses an opportunity to allow you to shoot yourself into your foot. You cannot provide a custom conversion operator from `T` to `const T` or vice versa

Comment: @idclev463035818: There's always time to slip it into C++23.

Comment: seems like you either you encountered some problem in code that you should have included in the question or this is a rather academical question (no problem about that), if it is the first, better ask about your actual problem

Comment: @idclev463035818 it's mostly academical. I do have to maintain some code and found a place where someone felt like checking the result of the const_cast for nullptr and i couldn't find any reason for it but also no explicit mention of this anywhere. I'd tend to conclude the same as n.'pronouns'm. but was wondering why i couldn't find a similar question anywhere. Maybe it's too obvious.